# Is it ok to assume normal distribution to count data if the QQ plot indicates normal distributed residuals?

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a Y count variable (# of  predation events) which is overdispersed.

Thus I should assume a negative binomial distribution (actually it is NB distribution seeing the  histogram). However, as I run the regression assuming normal distributed data, the residuals  follow a normal distribution. This allows me to assume a normal distribution or should I take negative binomial since its the variable distribution?

Comment: Why would normal residuals imply a normal Y? Linear regression doesn't assume normal distribution of variables.

Answer (score 3):

If there are enough counts then one can use the [Central Limit Theorem for Normal Distribution of Negative Binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165235/central-limit-theorem-for-normal-distribution-of-negative-binomial). In specific see the [answer to that question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/165247/99274). Otherwise, one uses the negative binomial. One can test both distributions for how well they fit the data to see which applies best.

Comment: well,  n= 20.  My question  is about  what would be  more  recommended: To assume  a Neg binomial distribution, since it´s variables distribution, or use a simple linear regressions once it's the simplest thing to do. I see choosing a "assumed" distribution a posteriori , a  bit wrong once you will obtain a result based on a mathematical and not necessarily a logical output 
can u guys clarify  these question?

Comment: @JulianNicholas Asked and answered, but, let me make it a bit more obvious. If one makes an assumption, "I think this is negative binomial," then one should test that assumption unless it is true that "I know dam well without a shadow of a doubt that this is a negative binomial." Ditto for comparing assumptions. Anything that is even vaguely hypothetical should be tested. Now, when publishing things, we just include the facts. "When the architect completes a fine building, he removes the scaffolding" ([Carl Friedrich Gauss](http://www.famousscientists.org/carl-friedrich-gauss/)).